# parse_url() returns an error when example.com is passed

Tags: php, parsing, parse-url

According to following code if `$host_name` is something like `example.com` PHP returns a notice: `Message: Undefined index: host` but on full URLs like `http://example.com` PHP returns `example.com`. I tried if statements with FALSE and NULL but didn't work.

```
$host_name = $this->input->post('host_name');
$parse = parse_url($host_name);
$parse_url = $parse['host'];
```

How can I modify the script to accept example.com and return it?

Comment: Well, it's not a valid URL. The protocol prefix is not optional, if the hostname is to be detected as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Upgrade your php.
   `5.4.7   Fixed host recognition when scheme is ommitted and a leading component separator is present.`
2. Add scheme manually: `if(mb_substr($host_name, 0, 4) !== 'http') $host_name = 'http://' . $host_name;`

Comment: In a second thought, you don't have a component separator, so only the second option left.

Answer (score 5):

You could just check the scheme is present using [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and prepend one if not present

```
$host_name = 'example.com';
if (!filter_var($host_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED)) {
    $host_name = 'http://' . $host_name;
}
$parse = parse_url($host_name);

var_dump($parse);

array(2) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(11) "example.com"
}
```

Comment: In some cases wont work. In your example `filter_var` checks not only mising schema

Answer (score 4):

Just add a default scheme in that case:

```
if (strpos($host_name, '://') === false) {
    $host_name = 'http://' . $host_name;
}
$parse = parse_url($host_name);
```

Comment: This is not a particularly robust piece of code though, is it?

Answer (score 0):

this is a sample function that returns the real host regardless of the scheme..

```
function gettheRealHost($Address) { 
   $parseUrl = parse_url(trim($Address)); 
   return trim($parseUrl[host] ? $parseUrl[host] : array_shift(explode('/', $parseUrl[path], 2))); 
} 

gettheRealHost("example.com"); // Gives example.com 
gettheRealHost("http://example.com"); // Gives example.com 
gettheRealHost("www.example.com"); // Gives www.example.com 
gettheRealHost("http://example.com/xyz"); // Gives example.com
```